# Saving current user as assigned agent to model when updating model

Tags: django

I have a list of jobs that are created by the admin. When one of the agents starts the job by updating the notes. I would like to save that agent to the job model.

**Models.py**

```
class Job(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  notes = models.TextField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class JobUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
  template_name = "jobs/job_update.html"
  queryset = Job.objects.all()
  form_class = JobModelForm

  def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("jobs:job-list")

  
  def job_update(request, pk):
    job = Job.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = JobModelForm(instance=job)
    if request.method == "POST":

      form = JobModelForm(request.POST, instance=job)

      if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
         
        return redirect("/jobs)
  context = {
      "form": form,
      "job': job
      }
   return render(request, "jobs/job_update.html", context)
```

****Forms.py** **

```
class JobModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
   model = Job
   fields = ('agent', 'start_date', 'notes')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you save appropriate Agent instance after form.save() is called ?

```
class JobUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
  template_name = "jobs/job_update.html"
  queryset = Job.objects.all()
  form_class = JobModelForm

  def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("leads:lead-list")

  
  def job_update(request, pk):
    job = Job.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = JobModelForm(instance=job)
    if request.method == "POST":

      form = JobModelForm(request.POST, instance=job)

      if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        
        # Here
        job.agent = Agent.objects.get(user=request.user)
        job.save()
         
        return redirect("/jobs)
  context = {
      "form": form,
      "job': job
      }
   return render(request, "jobs/job_update.html", context)
```

If you don't want to make another update query, then make custom form class is an option. You can override form class, allow it to be passed with agent instance, and set agent to job instance right after save method is called.

Comment: I added that to my view and the agent isn't saving. How would I create the custom form class?

Comment: Can you try to move job.agent = Agent.objects.get(user=request.user) line to right before form = JobModelForm(instance=job) ? Django model form would save that relation, I think !

Comment: Still not working. How would I go about creating the custom form class?